# Move image to a specific location on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have 12 pictures that I've dragged and dropped into the sheet directly from a windows folder. They are named "1 1.bmp", "1 2.bmp", "1 3.bmp" and so on.
I want to move them but how?

This is the code I'm trying:

```
Worksheets("R").Shapes("1 1").Top = Worksheets("R").Rows(24).Top
```

I don't know how reference to them. They are in the same folder as the .xlsm file. I've tried

```
Worksheets("R").Shapes("1 1.bmp").Top = Worksheets("R").Rows(24).Top
```

too.

Both examples from another question here on stack overflow.

What is the correct syntax?

/Jens

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to first insert picture to Excel and then adjust or resize the Picture. Later move the Picture towards down or right:

```
'Insert the Picture from the path if its not present already

Set myPict = Thisworkbook.sheets(1).Range("A1:B5").Parent.Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "mypic.jpg")

'Adjust the Picture location
    myPict.Top = .Top
    myPict.Width = .Width
    myPict.Height = .Height
    myPict.Left = .Left
    myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    'myPict.LockAspectRatio = msoTriStateMixed

'Change the width of the Picture
    myPict.Width = 85
'change the Height of the Picutre
    myPict.Height = 85
End With

'Select the Picutre
myPict.Select

'Move down the picture to 3 points. Negative value move up

Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3


'Move towards right upto 5 points. Negative value moves towards right
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrangePictures()
    Dim sh As Shape, anchor_cell As Range, v_shift As Long
    With Worksheets("R")
        Set anchor_cell = .Range("B24")             'left top corner for pictures
        v_shift = 0                                 'vertical shift for next picture
        For Each sh In .Shapes                      'loop over all the shapes in the sheet
            If sh.Type = msoPicture Then            'check if the shape is a picture
                sh.Top = anchor_cell.Top + v_shift  'move picture (vertical)
                sh.Left = anchor_cell.Left          'move picture (horizontal)
                v_shift = v_shift + sh.Height       'add vertical shift for next picture
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked but I need more control. Instead of ```If sh.Type = msopicture Then``` I would like to have ```If sh.Name = "1 1.bmp" Then``` and then some code. Then ```If sh.Name = "1 2.bmp" Then``` etc. I want all the pictures to be in different locations depending on the result of a search result. But I can't seem to find the name of the shapes. Or is ```sh.Name``` the one I need?

Comment: The name of the shape and the name of the file are completely different. Excel does not store the file name of the figure. If you want to operate with image file name when processing shapes, you have to enter the file name yourself in some shape property. For example in `Shape.Name` or `Shape.AlternativeText`. This can either be done manually or, if you are going to add images using VBA, programmatically at the same time as adding images.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it. I loaded all the ```Shape.Names``` in an array. Then I just have to write ``` If sh.Name = PicName(1) Then``` and then do that 12 times for all the different pictures. Thanks again!